# Color certain text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have made an online text program and I want to do something like:

```
 If Richtextbox1.text.contains("Tank") Then
  Tank.ForeColor = ForeColor.red
 End If
```

I just want the word "Tank" to be red.

Comment: Ok, will there be more than one instance inside of the RichTextBox?

Comment: Provide a code example of something you've tried.

Comment: Ive got something that will do you just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this example below.

```
Public Sub ColorText(box As RichTextBox, color As Color)
    box.[Select](start, 5)
    box.SelectionColor = color
End Sub
```

Comment: Read the tags. VB.NET, not C#.

Comment: That wont work either, what are you selecting exactly?

Comment: @user3326190 Instead of downvoting you should be able to translate 3 lines of C# code using an online .NET code converter.

Comment: Am sorry about this.I have changed it to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATED ANSWER:

I've written a solution using RegEx with the advantages of be able to use Regular expression patterns to find Words, with good features like CaseInsensitive, Forecolor, Backcolor, Font, and find multiple words.

Usage example 1:

```
ColorizeWord(RichTextBox1, "Tank", True,
             Color.Red, Color.Black,
             New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic))
```

Usage example 2:

```
ColorizeWords(RichTextBox1, {"Tank", "[0-9]"},
              IgnoreCase:=False,
              ForeColor:=Color.Red, BackColor:=Nothing, Font:=Nothing)
```

PS: If you don't want to set a parameter, set it as`Nothing`

Here is:

```
''' <summary>
''' Find a word on a RichTextBox and colorizes each match.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="RichTextBox">Indicates the RichTextBox.</param>
''' <param name="Word">Indicates the word to colorize.</param>
''' <param name="IgnoreCase">Indicates the ignore case.</param>
''' <param name="ForeColor">Indicates the text color.</param>
''' <param name="BackColor">Indicates the background color.</param>
''' <param name="Font">Indicates the text font.</param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if matched at least one word, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Private Function ColorizeWord(ByVal [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox,
                              ByVal Word As String,
                              Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = False,
                              Optional ByVal ForeColor As Color = Nothing,
                              Optional ByVal BackColor As Color = Nothing,
                              Optional ByVal [Font] As Font = Nothing) As Boolean

    ' Find all the word matches.
    Dim Matches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection =
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches([RichTextBox].Text, Word,
                                                     If(IgnoreCase,
                                                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                                                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None))

    ' If no matches then return.
    If Not Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        Return False
    End If

    ' Set the passed Parameter values.
    If ForeColor.Equals(Nothing) Then ForeColor = [RichTextBox].ForeColor
    If BackColor.Equals(Nothing) Then BackColor = [RichTextBox].BackColor
    If [Font] Is Nothing Then [Font] = [RichTextBox].Font

    ' Store the current caret position to restore it at the end.
    Dim CaretPosition As Integer = [RichTextBox].SelectionStart

    ' Suspend the control layout to work quicklly.
    [RichTextBox].SuspendLayout()

    ' Colorize each match.
    For Each Match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Matches

        [RichTextBox].Select(Match.Index, Match.Length)
        [RichTextBox].SelectionColor = ForeColor
        [RichTextBox].SelectionBackColor = BackColor
        [RichTextBox].SelectionFont = [Font]

    Next Match

    ' Restore the caret position.
    [RichTextBox].Select(CaretPosition, 0)

    ' Restore the control layout.
    [RichTextBox].ResumeLayout()

    ' Return successfully
    Return True

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Find multiple words on a RichTextBox and colorizes each match.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="RichTextBox">Indicates the RichTextBox.</param>
''' <param name="Words">Indicates the words to colorize.</param>
''' <param name="IgnoreCase">Indicates the ignore case.</param>
''' <param name="ForeColor">Indicates the text color.</param>
''' <param name="BackColor">Indicates the background color.</param>
''' <param name="Font">Indicates the text font.</param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if matched at least one word, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Private Function ColorizeWords(ByVal [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox,
                               ByVal Words As String(),
                               Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = False,
                               Optional ByVal ForeColor As Color = Nothing,
                               Optional ByVal BackColor As Color = Nothing,
                               Optional ByVal [Font] As Font = Nothing) As Boolean

    Dim Success As Boolean = False

    For Each Word As String In Words
        Success += ColorizeWord([RichTextBox], Word, IgnoreCase, ForeColor, BackColor, [Font])
    Next Word

    Return Success

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short, quick function that will color it any color & bold or italic the text found...

```
  Private Function FormatText(ByVal TextToFormat As String, ByVal TextFormat As Integer, ByVal TextColor As Color)
    Dim count As New List(Of Integer)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To rText.Text.Length - 1
        If rText.Text.IndexOf(TextToFormat, i) <> -1 Then
            'If the word is found add the index to the list
            count.Add(rText.Text.IndexOf(TextToFormat, i))
        End If
    Next

    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To count.Count - 1
            rText.[Select](count(i), TextToFormat.Length)
            Select Case TextFormat
                Case 1
                    rText.SelectionFont = New Font(rText.Font.FontFamily, rText.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                    rText.SelectionColor = TextColor
                Case 2
                    rText.SelectionFont = New Font(rText.Font.FontFamily, rText.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic)
                    rText.SelectionColor = TextColor
            End Select
            count.RemoveAt(i)
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

To use the function, heres an example:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If rText.Text.Contains("Tank") Then
        FormatText("Tank", 1, Color.Red)
    End If
 End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of my output for you to see...

[image: Screenshot]